# do I keep all files / setting when switching machine types on google compute engine?

Tags: cron, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running cronjob every 30 minutes - each cron job takes 2.5 hours to complete. I recently noticed "overutilized instance" message for virtual instance in gce with a recommendation to swith to another machine type. If I do so what will I lose ? I am running scripts using local code on the machine and don't want to lose any files.

Comment: You do backup important data, yes? While changing machine type generally keeps the same disk, other failures are possible. Always have another copy of valuable data per your organization's recovery objectives.

Answer (score 1):

**All your data will be in your VM after changing machine type**. As result of migrating to more powerful VM your cronjob could be finished in a less amount of time and overall performance of your VM will be improved. **Before any changes** you should protect your data by [creating a snapshot of your disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots).

To find more details have a look at the documentation [Applying sizing recommendations for VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances):

> **Compute Engine provides machine type recommendations to help you
>   optimize the resource utilization of your virtual machine (VM)**
>   instances. These recommendations are generated automatically based on
>   system metrics gathered by the Stackdriver Monitoring service over the
>   previous 8 days. Use these recommendations to resize your instance's
>   machine type to more efficiently use the instance's resources. This
>   feature is also known as rightsizing recommendations.

and

> Sizing recommendations are available free of charge.

In addition, you can find at [Changing a machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type):

> **For instances that are not part of a managed instance group, you can
>   change the machine type without affecting the instance's persistent
>   disk data (including installed applications and application data), SSH
>   keys, or other instance configurations such as instance metadata.** If
>   your instance uses an [ephemeral external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress), there is a
>   possibility that the IP address might change. To keep the IP address
>   from changing, [promote it to a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip).

and

> To change the machine type of a stopped instance, use the [Google Cloud
>   Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/?_ga=2.229693532.1173686192.1581927650-712562018.1576172652), the `setMachineType` method in the API, or the `instances
>   set-machine-type` command in `gcloud`. **You can only change the machine
>   type of a stopped instance and an instance is considered stopped only
>   when the instance is in the `TERMINATED` state.** It is not possible to
>   change the machine type of a running instance.